# Write a loop that parses json dictionaries using python

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, dictionary

I'm a beginner programmer and I've been trying to parse a json output file from an API GET request in order to pull longitude and latitude coordinates.

The JSON file looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9796idmwsxztbv/desktop.JPG?dl=0).

The JSON input file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/znv29iu05yc9hxl/data.txt?dl=0).

My code for parsing the json file currently looks like this:

```
ourResult = js['transactions'][0]['meta']

for majorkey, subdict in ourResult.iteritems():
     print majorkey
for subkey, value in subdict.iteritems():
     print subkey, value
```

This however, is only returning the one set of values within the 'location' key, and I'm trying to go a level further to pull the 'lon' and 'lat' values.

Any idea what code I should be using for this?

Comment: You should put the relevant parts of your json file in the post.

Comment: Did you try `ourResult = js['transactions'][1]['meta']` (1 instead of 0)?  The first value in the list doesn't contain lat/lon data.

Comment: instead of giving link, post the necessary json code.

Comment: Thanks! I included my entire code. To run the code, you'd have to import plaid-python, since this is a Plaid API test code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question you needed something like:

```
js = json.loads(response.content)
ourResult = js['transactions'][0]['meta']

for majorkey, subdict in ourResult.iteritems():
     print majorkey
     if type(subdict) == dict:
         for subkey, value in subdict.iteritems():
             print subkey, value
```

You can print `dict` of arbitrary depth using code

```
def print_dict_rec( indict ):
    for majorkey, subdict in indict.iteritems():
         if type(subdict) == dict:
            print majorkey
            print_dict_rec(subdict)
         else:
            print majorkey, subdict

print_dict_rec(ourResult)
```

Code for extracting all values for keys 'lat' and 'lon':

```
def get_values_json( js, res ):
    if type(js) == list:
        for e in js:
            get_values_json(e, res)
    elif type(js) == dict:
        for k,v in js.iteritems():
            if type(v) ==  dict or type(v) == list:
                get_values_json(v, res)
            else:
                if k == 'lat' or k == 'lon':
                    res[k].append(v)

res = {'lat':[], 'lon':[]}
get_values_json(js, res)
print res
```

Comment: So I tried this code and it just returned the same output i had before listing  the address, state values

Comment: @Vivienne Can you provide input as a text file? Then I can check and correct script.

Comment: Sure, this is the text file https://www.dropbox.com/s/snz1kqk5v74zoae/API%20code.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Vivienne I need input json file) I have not installed module plaid.

Comment: here is the json file (.txt) https://www.dropbox.com/s/znv29iu05yc9hxl/data.txt?dl=0

Comment: @Vivienne `ourResult = in['transactions'][0]['meta']` in this json doesn't contains 'lon' and 'lat' values. Please, try `ourResult = in['transactions'][14]['meta']`

Comment: When I use ourResult = js['transactions'][14]['meta']

and then use your code above (for majorkey...), it actually pulls "location city Metairie state LA zip 70003 coordinates {u'lat': 29, u'lon':-90} address 2625 David dr. Looks like I need to go a level deeper to pull coordinates?

Comment: @Vivienne Because `meta` is a `dict` with one key `location`. You can try `ourResult = js['transactions'][14]['meta']['location']`

Comment: Thank you!! This worked! Is there a way to write a loop that pulls all the lon and lat values through the json file?

Comment: So the code above also only pulls one set of values from the location key. Is there a way to pull values under every location key?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a print function somewhere in that last updated answer?

Comment: @Vivienne Yes, print res